# How is the implied risk neutral density affected when changing numeraire?

Tags: options, option-pricing, replication

For example i would like to price
\begin{equation*}
E^{Q} \left[ e^{-\int_{0}^{T}r_{s}^{cur}ds} f \left( S_{T_f}^{cur_1} \right) | \mathcal{F}_{0} \right] =  B_{cur}(0,T)E^{Q^{cur}_{T}}[ f(S_{T_f}^{cur_1})|\mathcal{F}_{0}]
\end{equation*}

I have at my disposition the risk neutral currency implied density for $S_{T_{f}}^{cur_1}$ obtained under $Q^{cur_1}$ from Breenden-Litzenberg theorem , how can I then value my option ?
At most I can say that it is equal to $B^{cur_1}(0,T) E^{Q^{cur_{1}}_{T}}[\frac{FX(cur_1,cur)(T)}{FX(cur_1,cur)(0)}f(S_{T_{f}}^{cur1})|\mathcal{F}_{0} ]$ but then i need to modelize the FX.

If i suppose my asset as well as my FX follows a BS model , I have the typical $e^{\int_{0}^{T_{f}} \rho_{S,FX}(t) \sigma_{S}(t) \sigma_{FX}(t) dt }$ factor that appears from changing my measure from foreign to domestic but how can i do the same thing with only some risk neutral implied density? I want to price with the least assumptions made.

Comment: Given this is quanto deal, you have to have the vol surface for the exchange rate and the correlation.

Comment: Ok but how do I account for these in my formula , I would like to find a form as to integrate with respect to $S_{T_{f}}$  density .

Comment: You can obtain risk neutral densities (marginal distributions) of asset and FX from their options market, but in order to price the quanto payout, you need a risk neutral joint terminal density for asset and FX, which is not observable unless you have liquid observable quotes for basket digitals paying $1_{S_T-K_1,FX_T-K_2}$